# How to solve the inequality $\binom{x}{2} \geq 183$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Today I was doing a problem where in I landed with the situation that.
$$\binom{x}{2}\geq 183$$
To do this, I had to use my calculator intensively. Well, I do understand that binomials are discrete integral functions and are not analogue, but is there some literature which involves the slope difference between these functions like for example, if I could write
$$f(n)=\binom{n}{a}$$
$$\Rightarrow \Delta f=\binom{n+1}{a}-\binom{n}{a}$$
and how would this function be expected to behave and stuff like that.
Please note I'm not a mathematician, I'm just an engineer and I have no mathematical background at all, hence this kind of silly question.

Comment: Note ${x\choose 2}=\tfrac12x(x-1)$, so you could've solved $\tfrac12x(x-1)\ge 183$. Also, $$\Delta f=\binom{n+1}{a}-\binom{n}{a}=\binom{n}{a-1}$$

Comment: @vrgutehagel: Aha, didn't think like that. My mind instant flew to what the graph of $f(n)$ would/could look like.

Comment: Nobody is "just" an engineer.